# How to define ${selected_resource_name} in intellij

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

In Eclipse , we can put ${selected_resource_name} at the working directory (Run /Debug configuration).

I can't find it in intellij. Instead of putting the path of the directory (working directory), i want to have like eclipse ${selected_resource_name} .

Is that possible ? Thxs

screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use $MODULE_DIR$ but it doesn't work

Comment: hey, did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Damn. I have exactly the same issue. Strange that this "feature" do not exists (as far as I know) in Intellij and also that no one else seems to miss it :)

Comment: Yes it's very weird :)